# How to find the last cell with a value at the end of a column that is shorter than other columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to add a value to the last row in a specific column in Google Sheets. Not all columns in the spreadsheet/table are of equal length so I can't simply look for the last row and add to a column. I need to find the next empty cell in a column and add the new value there. Looking through the docs I think involves the `getRange()` and `setValue()` functions but I think setting the actual range requires some additional coding to determine the next empty cell. Once I get that then I can do somtrhing like the following.

The button click triggers the `addRecord()` function

```
function addRecord(){

  var recVals = {};

  recVals.source = document.getElementById("source").value;
  recVals.medium = document.getElementById("medium").value;
  recVals.product = document.getElementById("product").value;

  google.script.run.userClicked(recVals);
}
```

Then in my apps scripts the `userClicked()` function runs and the value(s) are passed to it and written to the spreadsheet:

```
function userClicked(recVals){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId)
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  ws.appendRow([recVals.source, recVals.medium, recVals.product, new Date()]);
}
```

The problem is, that `appendRow()` adds the row at the end, below where I need the values to be set.

Comment: I think that you should add some sample data for the sheet. What do you mean by "next empty cell"? Which one was the first empty cell? What do you tried to find the "next empty cell"? (the appendRow example doesn't really  help to understand what you tried to achieve what you are looking for)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding an empty cell in a column using google sheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662987/finding-an-empty-cell-in-a-column-using-google-sheet-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getNextDataCell()` method of a range to get the first empty cell at the bottom of a particular column.  The code below starts the search at the bottom of the column and moves up through empty cells until it finds the first cell with a value.  You need the first empty cell, so 1 needs to be added to the found row value.

```
function getFirstEmptyCellInColumn(po){
  var columnLetterToGet,columnNumberToGet,direction,lastRow,lastRowInThisColWithData,
      rng,rowToBeginSearch,rowToSet,sh,ss,startOfSearch,totNmbrOfRows;
  
  /*
    po.ssId = The spreadsheet file ID
    po.sheetTabName - The name of the sheet tab to get
    po.columnToSearch - The column number in the sheet tab to find the last value
  */
  
  if (po.ssId) {//The file ID was passed in
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(po.ssId);
  } else {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  }
  
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(po.sheetTabName);

  lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log('lastRow: ' + lastRow)
  totNmbrOfRows = sh.getMaxRows();
  
  columnNumberToGet = po.columnToSearch;//The column number in the sheet to search
  
  columnLetterToGet = String.fromCharCode(96 + po.columnToSearch);//the column letter to get
  
  switch(true) {
    case (totNmbrOfRows - lastRow) > 1:
      rowToBeginSearch = lastRow + 2;
      break;
    case totNmbrOfRows === lastRow:
      rowToBeginSearch = lastRow;
      break;
  }
  
  startOfSearch = columnLetterToGet + rowToBeginSearch.toString();//Edit and replace with column letter to get
  //Logger.log('startOfSearch: ' + startOfSearch)
  
  rng = sh.getRange(startOfSearch);
  
  direction = rng.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);//This starts
  //the search at the bottom of the sheet and goes up until it finds the
  //first cell with a value in it
  
  //Logger.log('Last Cell: ' + direction.getA1Notation())
  
  lastRowInThisColWithData = direction.getRow();
  //Logger.log('lastRowInThisColWithData: ' + lastRowInThisColWithData)
  
  return lastRowInThisColWithData + 1;

}

function userClicked(recVals) {
  var o = {};
  
  o.ssId = "Put Spreadsheet ID here";
  o.sheetTabName = "Sheet Tab Name";
  o.columnToSearch = 3;
  
  var rowToSet = getFirstEmptyCellInColumn(o);
  
  var valuesToSet = [recVals.source, recVals.medium, recVals.product, new Date()];
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS ID");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("sheet tab name");
  
  sh.getRange(rowToSet, 1,1,valuesToSet.length).setValues([valuesToSet]);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 105, file "Code")` which is, imn my code, `ws.getRange(rowToSet, 1,1,valuesToSet.length).setValues([valuesToSet]);` This might have something to do with only passing one value instead of the array? I never intended to pass an array.

Comment: Ok. Think I got this figured out. Did a few things to the code. Dropped the +2 from `startOfSearch`. Then set `valuesSet` to 'recVals'. Then dropped `numRows` and `numColumns` from `ws.getRange`. Seems to work fine. This sound about right?

Comment: Glad you got it to work.  If one of your columns has values in cells all the way down to the very last row in the sheet, then you wouldn't need to use the `+2`.

Comment: Just got to figure out how to get that new value that I added to the spreadsheet column back into the dropdown without refreshing the entire app. Got the question open here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325897/how-do-i-add-a-new-value-to-a-google-sheet-from-a-text-field-in-a-web-app-and-th/62327737?noredirect=1#comment110366679_62327737